# How to hide Button in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm trying to make a button that shows text and another that removes it, this is what I have done so far.

When i click the Click me! button text shows, but it won't disappear when i click the hide button and i don't know why.

```js
<div class="butt">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunctionHide">Hide</button>
</div>
<p id="test"></p>

<script = "text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Andyduly";
}
</script>
<script = "text/javascript">
function myFunctionHide {
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML.object.style.display == "none";
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

2 issues in your code

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunctionHide">Hide</button>
```

should be

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunctionHide()">Hide</button>
```

---

```
function myFunctionHide {
   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML.object.style.display == "none";
}
```

should be

```
    function myFunctionHide() {
       document.getElementById("test").style.display = "none";
    }
```

`style` is property of the `element` and not the `innerHTML.object`

Also it is a better idea to avoid inline event handlers, which keeps your HTML cleaner also adhering to separation of concerns which makes your code more maintainable.

**HTML**

```
<div class="butt">
    <button type="button" id="btn_click">Click Me!</button>
    <button type="button" id="btn_hide">Hide</button>
</div>
<p id="test"></p>
```

**JS**

```
var elemTest = document.getElementById('test');

document.getElementById('btn_click').addEventListener('click', function () {
    elemTest.innerHTML = "Andyduly";
});

document.getElementById('btn_hide').addEventListener('click', function () {
    elemTest.style.display = "none";
});
```

You can encase your whole code inside a single script tag.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4mr2vpz/)**

Answer (score 1):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/hmp484as/)

To hide an element using Javscript, try something like

```
 document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none';
```

So replace your `<script>` as below

```
<script = "text/javascript">
    function myFunctionHide() {
    document.getElementById("test").style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

**There are many errors in your Javascript and HTML**

**Edited Javascript**

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Andyduly";
}

function myFunctionHide() {
    document.getElementById("test").style.display = "none";
}
```

You forgot to add `()` to your `myFunctionHide` in your Javascript.

Also, the **edited HTML** would be

```
<div class="butt">
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunctionHide()">Hide</button>
</div>
<p id="test"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all you syntax doesn't look right, should be

```
function myFunctionHide() {
   document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, I'm clearing the text from "test" P tag.

```js
<div class="butt">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunctionHide()">Hide</button>
</div>
<p id="test"></p>

<script = "text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Andyduly";
}
</script>
<script = "text/javascript">
function myFunctionHide() {
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "";
}

</script>
```

Comment: Corrected the answer. Thanks